# Need to have Rails notify a mailing list when it has a 500 error status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, logging, error-handling

I am developing an in house web application.

In development, it displays the whole stack trace page rendered in HTML, but obviously in production it just has a nice little "were sorry, we have been notified " message. Unfortunately no body is notified, and I want to fix that.

Ideally, that stack trace page rendered in HTML is what I would want to be emailed. But simply as much as the error message and file name would be nice, since right now finding the place the error occurred involves tracking down the sysadmin and have him email me the log file.

Is there a built-in way to enable this? What is the best-practice?

Some similar posts have said to use a custom Logger, but the documentation on this has been limited and unhelpful.

Can someone show me how to do this, or point me in the right direction and explain?
Thanks.

I am using Rails 2.3.8 and Passenger with apache2 if that matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exception Notifier](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/exception_notifier) plugin is what you are looking for. Here is a how-to on it:
http://engtech.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/rails-guide-exception-notifier-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party service like [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home) to collect this data.  They have a free account for low flow sites...

Comment: this is an intranet app, so that's not really what I am looking for, but it looks useful. Thanks!